# rails 3 relational validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a model, `Offer`, that belongs to a `User`. Users have an attribute `:prepaid_amount` that represents an amount of money, and `:bid_total`, which is the sum of all money bid on items, multiplied by the quantities of each bid. So, a User with two bids, one with `quantity => 3` and `amount => 10`, and another with `quantity => 2` and `amount => 3`, has a `bid_total` of 36.

If the prepaid_amount is greater than this value, everything is fine. Assume the `prepaid_amount` is 40.

If I want to validate a new bid from the user, of `quantity => 1`, then the amount of the bid can be any integer above 0, and up to 4. If it's zero, then 1*0, and the validation should fail because a bid must be greater than zero. If the amount is (say) 5, the bid should not validate, because 36 + 1*5 = 41, which is greater that the `prepaid_amount`.

How do I create such a validation in Rails 3 in the Offer model? Here's what I have, which doesn't work :

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, :presence => true, :numericality => true do
    validates :qty, :presence => {:if => Proc.new { |offer| (offer.user.prepaid_amount-offer.user.bid_total)/offer.amount >= offer.qty} }
  end


end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using a custom validation method?

```
validates_with :my_custom_validation_method

def my_custom_validation_method
   ...your code to validate...
end
```

One might argue that this is not the perfect rails way of validation but if your validation is so complex you might consider isolating it in its own method.

Comment: I guess that's my next step, if it solves the problem. Not sure that I see what I'm trying to do as that complex... but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: validates :qty, :numericality => {:less_than => Proc.new {|offer| (offer.user.prepaid_amount-offer.user.bid_total)/offer.amount}} will do it...

Comment: By complex I only meant that it's become an exercise of trying to weld the various validation parts together using the built in validation tools.